# pandas groupby column values (split on zero value)

Tags: python, pandas, grouping

I have timestamp data that I am trying to break up a data set into "chunks", based on whether the values a greater than 0. I think the best way to illustrate this is with an example... Imagine the data looks something like this data (where I have manually put in grouping information):

```
Timestamp, Value
2018-02-08 04:28:44, 0.0
2018-02-08 04:28:48, 0.0
2018-02-08 04:28:52, 0.5, group 1
2018-02-08 04:28:56, 0.5, group 1
2018-02-08 04:29:00, 5.3, group 1
2018-02-08 04:29:04, 5.3, group 1
2018-02-08 04:29:08, 5.3, group 1
2018-02-08 04:29:43, 4.7, group 1
2018-02-08 04:29:48, 4.7, group 1
2018-02-08 04:29:52, 3.7, group 1
2018-02-08 04:29:56, 3.7, group 1
2018-02-08 04:30:00, 2.3, group 1
2018-02-08 04:30:04, 2.3, group 1
2018-02-08 04:30:08, 2.3, group 1
2018-02-08 04:30:12, 0.0
2018-02-08 04:30:16, 0.0
2018-02-08 04:32:07, 0.0
2018-02-08 04:32:16, 0.0
2018-02-08 04:32:20, 2.1, group 2
2018-02-08 04:32:24, 2.1, group 2
2018-02-08 04:32:28, 2.1, group 2
2018-02-08 04:32:32, 4.7, group 2
2018-02-08 04:32:36, 4.7, group 2
2018-02-08 04:32:40, 9.0, group 2
2018-02-08 04:32:44, 9.0, group 2
2018-02-08 04:32:48, 9.0, group 2
```

...I think I could do this with this with the `groupby` function - so long as the grouping in information I have manually entered above was present). I guess the question is how would I break up a time-series like this into such groups?  (Should point out there is probably 100s or thousands of these groups).

Ideally there would be some kind of iterator that would spit out these groups - (there probably is one?) - but I just don't know what it is called, or what even begin looking for! (or indeed if my question title should be changed)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: second value is `group 1` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need get changes by conditions and create groups by [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), then add [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for replace to `NaN`s:

```
#comapre equality, not equality of 0
m = df['Value'].eq(0)
df['g'] = np.where(m, np.nan, (df['Value'].shift(-1).ne(0) & m).cumsum())
```

Or:

```
#comapre greater, less/equal of 0
m = df['Value'].gt(0)
df['g'] = np.where(m, (df['Value'].shift(-1).le(0) & m).cumsum(), np.nan)

              Timestamp  Value    g
0   2018-02-08 04:28:44    0.0  NaN
1   2018-02-08 04:28:48    0.0  NaN
2   2018-02-08 04:28:52    0.5  1.0
3   2018-02-08 04:28:56    0.5  1.0
4   2018-02-08 04:29:00    5.3  1.0
5   2018-02-08 04:29:04    5.3  1.0
6   2018-02-08 04:29:08    5.3  1.0
7   2018-02-08 04:29:43    4.7  1.0
8   2018-02-08 04:29:48    4.7  1.0
9   2018-02-08 04:29:52    3.7  1.0
10  2018-02-08 04:29:56    3.7  1.0
11  2018-02-08 04:30:00    2.3  1.0
12  2018-02-08 04:30:04    2.3  1.0
13  2018-02-08 04:30:08    2.3  1.0
14  2018-02-08 04:30:12    0.0  NaN
15  2018-02-08 04:30:16    0.0  NaN
16  2018-02-08 04:32:07    0.0  NaN
17  2018-02-08 04:32:16    0.0  NaN
18  2018-02-08 04:32:20    2.1  2.0
19  2018-02-08 04:32:24    2.1  2.0
20  2018-02-08 04:32:28    2.1  2.0
21  2018-02-08 04:32:32    4.7  2.0
22  2018-02-08 04:32:36    4.7  2.0
23  2018-02-08 04:32:40    9.0  2.0
24  2018-02-08 04:32:44    9.0  2.0
25  2018-02-08 04:32:48    9.0  2.0
```

Also if numbers in `g` column are not important, only need groups:

```
m = df['Value'].eq(0)
df['g'] = np.where(m, np.nan, m.cumsum())
print (df)
              Timestamp  Value    g
0   2018-02-08 04:28:44    0.0  NaN
1   2018-02-08 04:28:48    0.0  NaN
2   2018-02-08 04:28:52    0.5  2.0
3   2018-02-08 04:28:56    0.5  2.0
4   2018-02-08 04:29:00    5.3  2.0
5   2018-02-08 04:29:04    5.3  2.0
6   2018-02-08 04:29:08    5.3  2.0
7   2018-02-08 04:29:43    4.7  2.0
8   2018-02-08 04:29:48    4.7  2.0
9   2018-02-08 04:29:52    3.7  2.0
10  2018-02-08 04:29:56    3.7  2.0
11  2018-02-08 04:30:00    2.3  2.0
12  2018-02-08 04:30:04    2.3  2.0
13  2018-02-08 04:30:08    2.3  2.0
14  2018-02-08 04:30:12    0.0  NaN
15  2018-02-08 04:30:16    0.0  NaN
16  2018-02-08 04:32:07    0.0  NaN
17  2018-02-08 04:32:16    0.0  NaN
18  2018-02-08 04:32:20    2.1  6.0
19  2018-02-08 04:32:24    2.1  6.0
20  2018-02-08 04:32:28    2.1  6.0
21  2018-02-08 04:32:32    4.7  6.0
22  2018-02-08 04:32:36    4.7  6.0
23  2018-02-08 04:32:40    9.0  6.0
24  2018-02-08 04:32:44    9.0  6.0
25  2018-02-08 04:32:48    9.0  6.0
```

**Explanation**:

```
m = df['Value'].eq(0)
a = df['Value'].shift(-1).ne(0)
b = a & m
c = (a & m).cumsum()
d = np.where(m, np.nan, (df['Value'].shift(-1).ne(0) & m).cumsum())
df1 = pd.concat([df, m,a,b,c,pd.Series(d, index=df.index)], axis=1)
df1.columns = ['Timestamp','Value','==0','shifted != 0','chained by &','cumsum','out']
print (df1)
              Timestamp  Value    ==0  shifted != 0  chained by &  cumsum  out
0   2018-02-08 04:28:44    0.0   True         False         False       0  NaN
1   2018-02-08 04:28:48    0.0   True          True          True       1  NaN
2   2018-02-08 04:28:52    0.5  False          True         False       1  1.0
3   2018-02-08 04:28:56    0.5  False          True         False       1  1.0
4   2018-02-08 04:29:00    5.3  False          True         False       1  1.0
5   2018-02-08 04:29:04    5.3  False          True         False       1  1.0
6   2018-02-08 04:29:08    5.3  False          True         False       1  1.0
7   2018-02-08 04:29:43    4.7  False          True         False       1  1.0
8   2018-02-08 04:29:48    4.7  False          True         False       1  1.0
9   2018-02-08 04:29:52    3.7  False          True         False       1  1.0
10  2018-02-08 04:29:56    3.7  False          True         False       1  1.0
11  2018-02-08 04:30:00    2.3  False          True         False       1  1.0
12  2018-02-08 04:30:04    2.3  False          True         False       1  1.0
13  2018-02-08 04:30:08    2.3  False         False         False       1  1.0
14  2018-02-08 04:30:12    0.0   True         False         False       1  NaN
15  2018-02-08 04:30:16    0.0   True         False         False       1  NaN
16  2018-02-08 04:32:07    0.0   True         False         False       1  NaN
17  2018-02-08 04:32:16    0.0   True          True          True       2  NaN
18  2018-02-08 04:32:20    2.1  False          True         False       2  2.0
19  2018-02-08 04:32:24    2.1  False          True         False       2  2.0
20  2018-02-08 04:32:28    2.1  False          True         False       2  2.0
21  2018-02-08 04:32:32    4.7  False          True         False       2  2.0
22  2018-02-08 04:32:36    4.7  False          True         False       2  2.0
23  2018-02-08 04:32:40    9.0  False          True         False       2  2.0
24  2018-02-08 04:32:44    9.0  False          True         False       2  2.0
25  2018-02-08 04:32:48    9.0  False          True         False       2  2.0
```

Comment: Thanks - this looks good, but could you please expand on the logic a bit? ... struggling to understand the 2nd line in your examples

Comment: Thanks, but I have one question - why in second line `2018-02-08 04:28:48, 0.0, group 1` is `group 1`? It is typo?

Comment: Ahh yeah typo, will fix it now

Comment: I add explanation, I hope it help now.

Comment: That's fantastic - quick question, I don't suppose you know if this type of operation has a generic name or anything?

Comment: @djmac - Hard question, really I have no idea.